http.get() in Flutter doesn't throw an exception when connected to a network without internet access
I'm working on a Flutter app that downloads a list of images when a button is clicked. I’m using the http.get() method to download the images, but I’m facing an issue when the device is connected to a network without internet access. The http.get() call seems to hang indefinitely, and it doesn't throw any exceptions or return a timeout. Here's what I’m experiencing:

When there is no internet, but the device is connected to a Wi-Fi network without actual internet access, the request doesn’t fail or throw an exception.

I’ve tried using try-catch, .onError(), and checking the connectivity state with the connectivity_plus package.

Despite the device losing internet access or switching to a network without internet, the http.get() call never reaches the error handler or timeout.


What I've Tried:

Checking the network state using connectivity_plus to see if the device is connected to Wi-Fi.

Adding a SocketException handler to catch network-related errors.

Using .onError with the http.get() method to catch any exceptions.


import 'dart:io';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<void> downloadImage(String url) async {
  try {
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      // Image downloaded successfully
    } else {
      print('Failed to download image. Status code: ${response.statusCode}');
    }
  } on SocketException catch (e) {
    print('No internet connection or network issue: $e');
  } catch (e, stackTrace) {
    print('Error downloading image from $url: $e');
    print('Stack trace: $stackTrace');
  }
}

Problem:

No exception or error is caught when the device is connected to a network without internet. The app just gets stuck on the http.get() call.

I need to be able to detect the lack of internet access while still connected to a network and update the UI accordingly.


Question:
How can I ensure that http.get() throws an exception or handles the case where the device is connected to a network without internet access in Flutter? Is there a better way to detect this condition and break the download process?
Additional Info:

I'm using Flutter with the http package.

I prefer not to use timeouts for the request.

I’m already using the connectivity_plus package to track network changes.


Any guidance or help would be appreciated!

You probably have to wait for a platform timeout... it might be long like 30 seconds or even 5 minutes.  If you need to abort definitely sooner than that, add a timeout of your own.

can add timeout but sometime it take more than 92 second to download the image by this logic timeout will not work for me
